# How to update Apache Directory LDAP API version M28 with 2.0.13 mina-core dependency?

Tags: apache, maven

I am using api-ldap-client-all-1.0.0-M28.jar as maven dependency in my project. Now api-ldap-client-all-1.0.0-M28.jar internally uses mina-core 2.0.7 version which has 100% CPU usage issues ([DIRMINA-988](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRMINA-988), [DIRMINA-1001](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRMINA-1001)) which are resolved in latest version(2.0.13) of mina-core. Now I want to update api-ldap-client-all-1.0.0-M28.jar with mina-core 2.0.13. What will be the procedure to do that?